# for loop is ending prematurely

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im starting to learn python and ive written a program that gives the user six tries to guess a random number generated between 1 and 20. After the user enters one of six guesses the guess is sent into a for loop and the guess is then evaluated by an if and a elif statement to determine whether the guess is below the secret number or above it and tells the user either too low or too high, or if the user guesses the number correctly, the for loop is then stopped by a else statement containing a break statement. The issue i have though is that after two guesses are entered the for loop ends prematurely and exits the loop with out giving the option of guessing again. i dont why the for loop is only being executed, any suggestio

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Im thinking of a number between 1 and 20')

for guessesTaken in (1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())
    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Wow you guessed my number in' + int(guessTaken) + 'guesses')
else:
    print('Nope. The number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: as x00 pointed out, the best practice here would be to use `range(n)` with n equal to the number of guesses allowed. Iterating over the tuple (1, 7) will loop twice, i.e. the number of elements in the tuple. (1, 7) does not create a range to loop over.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is iterating over the elements in the <s>list</s> tuple (1, 7) - two elements, one and seven.

You should have

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
```

range(1, 7) will return a list of 6 elements, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and so the for loop will iterate over those 6 elements.

Also, you spelled `guessesTaken` two ways:  `guessesTaken` and `guessTaken`.

Answer (score 1):

Brenda is almost right, except that `(1,7)` is a tuple, not a list. And

```
for guessesTaken in range(7): # or 6, not sure about your true intentions
```

will be a little bit shorter